Source for imagining a rabbinic author before you
Whatever the original/straightforward meaning of this verse might be, some have understood the phrase " וְהָי֥וּ עֵינֶ֖יךָ רֹא֥וֹת אֶת־מוֹרֶֽיךָ" (Yeshayah 30) to be instructive, that "your eyes should see your teacher" (at least, that's what people sometimes put on posters containing photos of famous rabbinic personalities).
I remember seeing a much stronger formulation of this idea quoted in the introduction of a certain sefer: that there is a value in actually imagining the figure of a rabbinnic author standing before you while you study that author's works. I don't remember the book I saw this in, or if there was any connection made to the verse in Yeshayah, but I believe it was quoted from some obscure midrash, or possibly a kabbalistic work. Do you know of such a rabbinic source?
